# Speeding up the process to find elements which are divisible by elements of the same array

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I came across a problem:

Given an array, find the **max** count of this array, where *count* for an element in the array is defined as the no. of elements from this array which can divide this element.

Example: **max** count from the array `[2,2,2,5,6,8,9,9]` is 4 as 6 or 8 can be divided by 2,2,2 and by themselves.

My approach is:

1. Sort the array.
2. Make a set from this array (in a way such that even this set is sorted in non-descending order).
3. Take another array in which the array indices are initialized to the no. of times an element appears in the original array. Example: in above example element '2' comes three times, hence index '2-1' in this new array will be initialized to 3, index '9-1' will be initialized to 2 as '9' comes 2 times in this array.
4. Using two loops I am checking the divisibility of largest (moving largest to smallest) element in the set with smallest (moving smallest to largest) element of the set.

**Conditions**

> 1 <= arr[i] <= 10000

> 1 <= i <= 10000

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

void arr_2_set(int *arr, int arr_size,int *set, int *len) 
{
    int index = 0;
    int set_len = 0;
    int ele = INT_MIN;

    qsort(arr,arr_size,sizeof(int),cmp);

    while(index < arr_size)
    {
        if(ele != arr[index])
        {
            ele = arr[index];
            set[set_len] = ele;
            set_len++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    *len = set_len;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[]={2,2,2,5,6,8,9,9}; //array is already sorted in this case
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int set[size];
    int index = 0;

    int set_len = 0;
    arr_2_set(arr, size, set, &set_len); //convert array to set - "set_len" is actual length of set

    int rev = set_len-1; //this will point to the largest element of set and move towards smaller element
    int a[100000] = {[0 ... 99999] = 0}; //new array for keeping the count

    while(index<size)
    {
        a[arr[index] -1]++;
        index++;
    }

    int half;
    int max=INT_MIN;
    printf("set len =%d\n\n",set_len);
    for(;rev>=0;rev--)
    {
        index = 0;
        half = set[rev]/2;

        while(set[index] <= half)
        {
            if(set[rev]%set[index] == 0)
            {
                a[set[rev] -1] += a[set[index]-1]; //if there are 3 twos, then 3 should be added to count of 8
                //printf("index =%d  rev =%d  set[index] =%d  set[rev] =%d count = %d\n",index,rev,set[index],set[rev],a[set[rev] -1]);
            }
            if(max < a[set[rev]-1])
                max = a[set[rev]-1];
            index++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",max);

    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is how can I speed up this program? I was able to pass 9/10 test cases - for the 10th test case (which was hidden), it was showing *"Time Limit Exceeded"*.

Comment: I think you can speed up by using the fact that you only have to search up to half the bigger number looking for divisors?

Comment: There's probably some way to take advantage of this: If divisorCount(x) = n, and x divides y, then divisorCount(y) = n + 1.

Comment: @ojblass if the original array is `2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,10`, then the set would be `2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` - so if I check for only half the bigger no. then we will miss the count of 4?

Comment: @Barmar can you explain in case the array is `2,3,6,12`.

Comment: I haven't actually figured out HOW to take advangtage of it, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Tip: why `(int)` in `qsort(arr,arr_size,sizeof(int),cmp);`?  Because it is the type of the element?  Skip that, use `qsort(arr,arr_size,sizeof arr[0],cmp);` to get the right size, even if the type changes.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus The conditions say `10000` (**ten** thousand). But the code has an array of size `100000` (**hundred** thousand). Why is that array so big?

Comment: @user3386109 it doesn't matter as the indices of that array which are being referred are limited and fixed - indices which are referred depend on the elements of original array - say the element in original array is `n` then it would be present at index `n-1` in the array `a` which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For creating a set and finding the count - use a single `while` loop, when the size of array is big then using a single loop will matter a lot.
- In the later half section where two nested loops are there - don't go from largest to smallest element. Go from smallest to largest element **while** checking which largest element with index lower than the current element can divide this element, add the count of that element to the current element's count (using `set[i]/2` logic will still hold here). This way you'll avoid a lot of divisions. Example: if set is `{2,3,4,8}` in this case, lets say your current position is `8` then you go down till largest element smaller than or equal to `8` which can divide `8` and add it's count to current element's (`8`) count.

Answer (score 1):

> for the 10th test case (which was hidden), it was showing *"Time Limit Exceeded"*.

That may suggest a more time efficient algorithm is expected.

The posted one, first sorts the array (using `qsort`) and then copies only the unique values into another array, `set`.

Given the constraints on the possible values, it may be cheaper to implement a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) algorithm.

The last part, which searches the maximum number of dividends, can then be implemented as a sieve, using an additional array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum constraints {
  MAX_VALUE = 10000
};

int count_dividends(size_t n, int const *arr)
{
  // The actual maximum value in the array will be used as a limit.
  int maxv = 0;
  int counts[MAX_VALUE + 1] = {0};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if ( counts[arr[i]] == 0  &&  arr[i] > maxv )
    {
      maxv = arr[i];
    }
    ++counts[arr[i]];
  }

  // Now, instead of searching for the dividends of an element, it
  // adds the number of factors to each multiple.
  // So, say there are two elements of value 3, it adds 2 to all
  // the multiples of 3 in the total array.
  int totals[MAX_VALUE + 1] = {0};
  int count = 0;
  // It starts from 2, it will add the numbers of 1's once, at the end.
  for (int i = 2; i <= maxv; ++i)
  {
    // It always skips the values that weren't in the original array.
    if ( counts[i] != 0 )
    {
      for ( int j = 2 * i; j <= maxv; j += i)
      {
        if ( counts[j] != 0 )
          totals[j] += counts[i];
      }
      if ( counts[i] + totals[i] > count )
      {
        count = counts[i] + totals[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return count + counts[1];
}

int main(void)
{
  {
    int a[] = {2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 14, 8, 2, 12, 1, 13, 10, 2, 8, 5, 9, 1};
    size_t n = (sizeof a) / (sizeof *a);

    // Expected: 10, because of 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 8 8 
    printf("%d\n", count_dividends(n, a));
  }
  {
    int a[] = {2, 4, 5, 2, 7, 10, 9, 8, 2, 4, 4, 6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6};
    size_t n = (sizeof a) / (sizeof *a);

    // Expected: 9, because of 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 8 8
    printf("%d\n", count_dividends(n, a));
  }
}
```